# Boost Converter Inefficiency

Tags: pwm, boost, step-up

I in my design I have boost converter (using PAM2423) which is powered by LiFePO4 (3.2V) cell. It works and gives accurate output but it is very inefficient. I checked voltage on the coil and I think strange pulses is the reason of it. All the other components cant cause so much loses (I use ceramic capacitors both on output and input, low Resistance coil and low voltage drop diode). Here is scope of voltage on the coil and circuit itself[image]
[image: Strange Pulses]Output Ripple[image]
Do you have any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: Show your circuit (with test load) and state the power efficiency you measure and what you expected.

Comment: Efficiency level is somewhere around 55%, was expecting 85-90%.

Comment: Value of C6? What’s heating up?

Comment: 22uf, there are 3 of them in parallel to have low ESR and high capacity. Mostly chip is getting hot. Coil also warms up.

Comment: What’s the load current?

Comment: Load current is 1A

Answer (score 1):

I believe those "strange pulses" are actually your 520 kHz switching waveform. Although Diodes Inc. really half-asses their data sheets, it's likely that under light load conditions it will enter discontinuous mode. This is when it's achieved the required output voltage, and further current will put it over the top. Then it stops switching until the voltage droops, and restarts to maintain the output voltage.

Under these light load conditions, the efficiency will be terrible, since the controller and switching currents are higher than the output current. This isn't usually a problem, because the total current in is still fairly small. Have you measured it with a load?

Comment: Update--on the top of page 6, the spec does in fact mention at the end of the paragraph that it will enter "pulse skipping" mode under light load conditions.  I believe this is their description of the above.

Comment: Correct, the converter is clearly discontinuous and pulse-skipping- You can see the diode is conducting until L runs out of current when it rings down to Vin.  Since the output at this point is above the set point it stays there until it falls enough to start the switching cycle again.  As you said, no surprise that efficiency is poor at very light loads, though there are better boost converters if high efficiency at light loads is required.

Comment: As an example of a better part look here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61256.pdf Quite a bit better than 80% efficiency at 1mA load current.

Comment: The problem is that it should have efficiency about 80% with 5V @ 1A while, I have 60% under that load. I am pretty sure that it is not because of coil/diode and other components because chip is getting hot very hot. I feel that the problem is something else. Might be grounding?

Comment: What does your output ripple look like?  It seems like it should be large, since your switching waveform indicates a lot of pumping (trying to drive lots of current when it comes out of pulse skipping, then rapidly cutting back and skipping more pulses).  It would be interesting to see the effect of more inductance, if only for diagnostic reasons.  Looking at your switching waveform, I suspect you have ~1VP-P of ripple on your output.

Comment: Yes, it is around 1V (650 mV) @ 1A load.

Comment: Then you're looking at a stability issue.  Sadly, Diodes Inc, as far as I can tell, offers no guidance on using the COMP pin.  I'd try removing C20 to see what that does, then maybe put a 500K trimpot in for R21.  If I can't adjust R21 to my satisfaction, I'd then try making C19 smaller.  Keep an eye on the effects of each on the output, this will guide you if further tweaks are needed.  It might be easier to stabilize with a larger inductor.  Ultimately, you should have no ripple except at the switching frequency (and harmonics).

Comment: Very useful details are available at http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva301/slva301.pdf and at https://www.richtek.com/en/Design%20Support/~/media/DT_PDF/Stability_design_tips.pdf.

Comment: I am HIGHLY suspicious of that value for C20! 2.2n with 820k across it has a time constant best measured with a calendar, it could be right, but I would be expecting something more in the few tens of pF.